# How to deploy website to intranet (IIS) via Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I am planning to use azure devops for CI/CD. The .NET 5 website needs to be deployed on IIS located on-premise. Can azure devops be configured to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the [IIS Web App Manage task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) and [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops).

```
# IIS web app deploy
# Deploy a website or web application using Web Deploy
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    webSiteName: 
    #virtualApplication: # Optional
    #package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip' 
    #setParametersFile: # Optional
    #removeAdditionalFilesFlag: false # Optional
    #excludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: false # Optional
    #takeAppOfflineFlag: false # Optional
    #additionalArguments: # Optional
    #xmlTransformation: # Optional
    #xmlVariableSubstitution: # Optional
    #jSONFiles: # Optional
```

Comment: Where is the on prem server detail to be added?

Comment: you need to install an agent in the on-prem machine, then run above task with this agent.